# Shopware 5 Responsive theme inheritance

Tags: shopware

I want to create my own theme on shopware5 with Bootstrap responsive framework. When I tried this on my test site, I noticed, the default Responsive css files are conflicting with my Bootstrap files. Bootstrap css (less files) are in my new theme less folder.

However, the developer guide saying “If you have extensive theme changes, it's recommended to adapt the Less file subfolders of the Responsive theme to have a better overview”

What does this mean actually? Can I put my bootstrap files into Responsive theme folder. Generally, as a common rule, we do not update parent files in case the new updates can alter our codes at any time.  What is the correct method to use our own responsive template in Shopware5 theming.

Other than above 
I tried to post my question on Shopware 5 support but unfortunately I couldn’t find an English support for this tool. Could you please tell me if any support is available in English for this tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. You have to place the bootstrap `.less` files into your own theme-folder.

First you should read [Getting started with LESS](https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/less/) of Shopware.

After that you will have to known how to [adding less files to your theme](https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/theme-startup-guide/#adding-less-files-to-your-theme).

**You have to use the `Bare`-Theme**

Have in mind that you have to extend the `Bare`-Theme and not the `Responsive`-Theme of Shopware because you want to use Bootstrap instead of Shopware-Responsive-Framework.

Comment: Hi, you are correct; I tried your Idea with a new theme. However, my new theme html doesn’t override the parent ‘Bare’ theme Html. I can see my css are loading fine. Is there anything to do when we extend bare theme.

Comment: This is solved, My theme was cached somewhere. I have disabled my theme cache but still the theme get cached its html source.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the whole structure of the template-engine into Bootstrap you have to change every single file. There is a Bootstrap based template available at the Shopware Plugin Store:

http://store.shopware.com/swf01015/shopware-bootstrap-theme.html